# Call PHP file inside an HTML without using input tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Is there any way to call a PHP file inside an HTML document without using an input tag?

I am trying to display some results of my database (as a table) using the form tag (`file2.php`) but I realize that the only way to display the results, is to have an input tag inside the form tag. Is there any way to simply display the results in my HTML website without using inputs?

**Code:**

```
<html>
<body> 
 <img src="file1.php"> 
 <form action="file2.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
 </form>
</body>
<html>

My file2.php is
---
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'yyyy');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use' .DB_NAME .':' . mysql_error()); 
}

 $cid=$_COOKIE["cid"];
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE PID='$cid' ORDER BY SUBTIME ASC;";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 echo "<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <th> SUBMISSION DATE/TIME </th>
  <th> SYS </th>
  <th> DIA </th>
  <th> PULSE </th>
  <th> WEIGHT </th>
  </tr>";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['SUBTIME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['SYS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['DIA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['PULSE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['WEIGHT'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

  if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error:' .mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: use include_once or require_once

Comment: what is the problem to rename the .html file to .php? You want just a link? Use <a href="file2.php">link</a>

Comment: Thanks!Is it possible without changing the html file to php?

Comment: @Stefania Why is it a problem to change name of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a PHP file in an HTML file. You need to change the extension of the HTML to PHP and use `include()`.

```
<?php 
    include 'form2.php';
?>
```

That is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @Caio, hmmm... Now that I think about it.. It shouldn't

Comment: I don't understand why you put a include inside the action attribute?
I think your first answer was fine...  just use the include and change the extension from .html to .php

Comment: I just rename the html file to php and then I added <?php 
    include 'file2.php'; ?>  this line in the html part without using any form.